# SQL error: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Okay, I'm getting an error: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected when I run this query. I don't understand I have the FROM statement in the following. Thanks.

```
    ResultSet rs = 
stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Airline, 
Avg((extract(day from (Actual_time - Scheduled_time)) * 24 * 60) (extract(hour from (Actual_time - Scheduled_time)) * 60) (extract(minute from (Actual_time - Scheduled_time)))) 
AS 'Average Delay in Minutes' 
FROM Flight Group by Airline");
```

Comment: Try putting quotes around Average Delay in Minutes

Comment: Just changed it still would not work.

Comment: At the very least it is missing a comma/operator. `60) (extract` <- I don't think so. Instead of running this from code and waiting for an Exception (or using SO as an online debugging service), use an *interactive client* to break down and reconstruct the SQL to resolve syntax issues.

Comment: Should be double quotes around the column alias.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps formatting the code can make things easier to read

Putting spaces in a field name is bad idea

```
SELECT
    Airline, 
    AVG(
        (EXTRACT(DAY FROM (Actual_time - Scheduled_time)) * 24 * 60)
        (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (Actual_time - Scheduled_time)) * 60)
        (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (Actual_time - Scheduled_time)))
    ) AS Average_delay_in_minutes 
FROM Flight
GROUP BY Airline;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have logic like `(day)(hour)(minute)`.  Presumably, you want `+` between the components:

```
SELECT Airline, 
       Avg((extract(day from (Actual_time - Scheduled_time)) * 24 * 60) +
           (extract(hour from (Actual_time - Scheduled_time)) * 60) +
           (extract(minute from (Actual_time - Scheduled_time)))
          ) AS AverageDelayInMinutes
FROM Flight
Group by Airline;
```

Your parentheses seems to balance in the original query, so I suspect the problem is the missing operator.